# Doubt in creating a Sierpinski carpet using TSQL (set based)

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

[TSql Challenge 56](http://beyondrelational.com/puzzles/tsql/56/english/create-a-sierpinski-carpet-using-tsql.aspx) is over .... So I can safetly ask doubt on that

I have tried to solve the problem as under

```
WITH CTE AS 
( 
    SELECT   
            id ,
                        level ,
                        1 AS row ,
                        REPLICATE('X', POWER(3, level)) AS carpet
               FROM     TC56
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   id ,
                        level ,
                        row + 1 ,
                        carpet
               FROM     CTE
               WHERE    Row < POWER(3, level)
             )
    SELECT  
        id
        ,row
        ,carpet
    FROM    CTE
    ORDER BY id,row
```

But the output is not at par with the one specified.. My output is as under

```
id row carpet
1 1 X
2 1 XXX
2 2 XXX
2 3 XXX
3 1 XXXXXXXXX
3 2 XXXXXXXXX
3 3 XXXXXXXXX
3 4 XXXXXXXXX
3 5 XXXXXXXXX
3 6 XXXXXXXXX
3 7 XXXXXXXXX
3 8 XXXXXXXXX
3 9 XXXXXXXXX
```

The problem is that I am not able to fill positions that needs to be filled with empty spaces

Help needed

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that can be extended to be able to generate Sierpinski carpets of greater orders. Currently it can correctly generate Sierpinski carpets up to the 3<sup>rd</sup> order.

By 'correctly' I mean, it *can* produce all the necessary rows for greater order patterns, but presently additional columns need to be added (those `sortN` ones) to provide the correct arrangement of the rows. I've added comments where modifications are required.

```
WITH TC56 (id, level) AS (
  SELECT 1, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 2
),
x AS (
  SELECT CAST('X' AS varchar(max)) AS x
),
rec_cte AS (
  SELECT
    x,
    level = 0,
    sort1 = 0,
    sort2 = 0,
    sort3 = 0
    /* add new columns here */
  FROM x
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    x = CAST(x.x + CASE TC56.level WHEN 1 THEN SPACE(LEN(x.x)) ELSE x.x END + x.x
             AS varchar(max)),
    level = x.level + 1,
    sort1 = TC56.level,
    sort2 = (TC56.level * 3 + x.sort1) % 3,
    sort3 = ((TC56.level * 3 + x.sort1) * 3 + x.sort2) % 3
    /* computations of the new columns' values follow the above pattern; e.g.
    sort4 = (((TC56.level * 3 + x.sort1) * 3 + x.sort2) * 3 + x.sort3) % 3 */
  FROM rec_cte x
    CROSS JOIN TC56
  WHERE x.level < 3  /* the necessary level to generate;
                   the last sortN's N number defines the maximum value
                   for which the pattern produced is guaranteed to be correct;
                   in this script the last sort column is sort3, so
                   the maximum 'supported' order is 3 */
)
SELECT * FROM rec_cte
ORDER BY level, sort1, sort2, sort3 /* add the new columns here */
```

Here's the result:

```
x                              level       sort1       sort2       sort3
------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
X                              0           0           0           0
XXX                            1           0           0           0
X X                            1           1           0           0
XXX                            1           2           0           0
XXXXXXXXX                      2           0           0           0
X XX XX X                      2           0           1           0
XXXXXXXXX                      2           0           2           0
XXX   XXX                      2           1           0           0
X X   X X                      2           1           1           0
XXX   XXX                      2           1           2           0
XXXXXXXXX                      2           2           0           0
X XX XX X                      2           2           1           0
XXXXXXXXX                      2           2           2           0
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    3           0           0           0
X XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX X    3           0           0           1
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    3           0           0           2
XXX   XXXXXX   XXXXXX   XXX    3           0           1           0
X X   X XX X   X XX X   X X    3           0           1           1
XXX   XXXXXX   XXXXXX   XXX    3           0           1           2
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    3           0           2           0
X XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX X    3           0           2           1
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    3           0           2           2
XXXXXXXXX         XXXXXXXXX    3           1           0           0
X XX XX X         X XX XX X    3           1           0           1
XXXXXXXXX         XXXXXXXXX    3           1           0           2
XXX   XXX         XXX   XXX    3           1           1           0
X X   X X         X X   X X    3           1           1           1
XXX   XXX         XXX   XXX    3           1           1           2
XXXXXXXXX         XXXXXXXXX    3           1           2           0
X XX XX X         X XX XX X    3           1           2           1
XXXXXXXXX         XXXXXXXXX    3           1           2           2
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    3           2           0           0
X XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX X    3           2           0           1
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    3           2           0           2
XXX   XXXXXX   XXXXXX   XXX    3           2           1           0
X X   X XX X   X XX X   X X    3           2           1           1
XXX   XXXXXX   XXXXXX   XXX    3           2           1           2
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    3           2           2           0
X XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX X    3           2           2           1
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    3           2           2           2
```