# How to generate spaces between letters in Sql Server 2005 (Set Based)

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

**Input**

```
Column
ab2e
mnop
a2t1y
```

**output**

```
Id  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5  Col6
1    a    b              e
2    m    n    o     p
3    a               t        y
```

The numbers indicates the number of spaces
Since in the first input, there is 2 after b, so the letter e will appear after 2 spaces from b.
In the second input since there is no space, the the letters will appear after each other

Thanks

Comment: You can only do stuff in a set-based manner, if you have sets of data, e.g. a lot of rows of data. String manipulation is **not** a set-based operation, and not something SQL Server is terribly good at...

Comment: I think you should have a look at this TSQL challenge http://beyondrelational.com/puzzles/tsql/58/english/playing-chess-in-tsql-part-1.aspx. I guess that the best solution to that problem will be published when the challenge is over. Perhaps something you can use.

Comment: @Mikael: I'm sure the OP [has already been acquainted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304734/doubt-in-creating-a-sierpinski-carpet-using-tsql-set-based) with that site.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already got a way of distributing a 'normal' string's contents between the columns and only need a solution for expanding strings like `ab2e` into strings like `ab[space][space]e`, then here's a possible solution:

```
DECLARE @InputString varchar(100), @pos int, @result varchar(100);
SET @InputString = 'a2t1y';
SET @result = @InputString;
SET @pos = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @result);
WHILE @pos <> 0 BEGIN
  SET @result = STUFF(@result, @pos, 1, SPACE(SUBSTRING(@result, @pos, 1)));
  SET @pos = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @result);
END
SELECT @result;
```

The output:

```
---------------------
a  t y
```

It would probably be a nice idea to implement it as a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ExpandString (@String varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @pos int, @result varchar(100);
  SET @result = @String;
  SET @pos = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @result);
  WHILE @pos <> 0 BEGIN
    SET @result = STUFF(@result, @pos, 1, SPACE(SUBSTRING(@result, @pos, 1)));
    SET @pos = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @result);
  END
  RETURN @result;
END
```

so you could call it on a column like this:

```
SELECT …, dbo.ExpandString(t.SomeColumn), …
```

It should be noted, though, that this solution only supports single-digit 'macros', i.e. `a12b` would be converted to `a[1 space][2 spaces]b` with this function, which is not necessarily what you'd expect. So, if you need it to recognise integers as sequences of numeric characters between non-numerics, here's an alternative solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ExpandString (@String varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @pos int, @lastpos int, @len int, @isnum bit,
          @sub varchar(100), @result varchar(100);
  SET @result = '';
  SET @pos = 1;
  SET @len = LEN(@String);
  SET @isnum = ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@String, @pos, 1));
  WHILE @pos <= @len BEGIN
    SET @lastpos = @pos;
    WHILE @pos <= @len AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@String, @pos, 1)) = @isnum
      SET @pos = @pos + 1;
    SET @sub = SUBSTRING(@String, @lastpos, @pos - @lastpos);
    SET @result = @result + CASE @isnum WHEN 1 THEN SPACE(@sub) ELSE @sub END;
    SET @isnum = @isnum ^ 1;
  END;
  RETURN @result;
END
```

Both versions recognise numbers both at the beginning and at the end of the input string.

Comment: That's fine.. but how to do it in set based

Comment: @agnihotri: What exactly should be set-based?